# Detecting bluetooth headphones connection with udev / bluez

Tags: udev, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

What I'm trying to achieve: set bluetooth headphones as the default sink in pulseaudio when they are connected, and set back to laptop speakers when disconnected.

Why: my laptop detects all four potential HDMI outputs as audio sinks, and frequently decides to set one of them as the default. I am tired of opening up pavucontrol and changing this.

Problem: I have looked at writing a udev rule for this, but unfortunately the data from udevadm is not super helpful.

`udevadm monitor` output when connecting my headphones:

```
~ > udevadm monitor                                                                             
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[74617.230946] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [74617.232667] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[74618.266963] add      /devices/virtual/input/input47 (input)
KERNEL[74618.267067] add      /devices/virtual/input/input47/event22 (input)
UDEV  [74618.269394] add      /devices/virtual/input/input47 (input)
UDEV  [74618.364725] add      /devices/virtual/input/input47/event22 (input)
```

`udevadm info` output for the devices added:

```
~ > udevadm info -ap /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256

...

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256':
    KERNEL=="hci0:256"
    SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0':
    KERNELS=="hci0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="bluetooth"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256':
    KERNEL=="hci0:256"
    SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0':
    KERNELS=="hci0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="bluetooth"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
```

```
~ > udevadm info -ap /devices/virtual/input/input47

...

  looking at device '/devices/virtual/input/input47':
    KERNEL=="input47"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{capabilities/abs}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/ev}=="100007"
    ATTR{capabilities/ff}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/key}=="2fc800 145200000000 0 10300 49e800000c00 e16800000000f f810000010000ffc"
    ATTR{capabilities/led}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/msc}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/rel}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/snd}=="0"
    ATTR{capabilities/sw}=="0"
    ATTR{id/bustype}=="0005"
    ATTR{id/product}=="4020"
    ATTR{id/vendor}=="009e"
    ATTR{id/version}=="0481"
    ATTR{inhibited}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="gtf qc35ii (AVRCP)"
    ATTR{phys}=="3c:e9:f7:f2:f6:10"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
```

```
~ > udevadm info -ap /devices/virtual/input/input47/event22

...

  looking at device '/devices/virtual/input/input47/event22':
    KERNEL=="event22"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/virtual/input/input47':
    KERNELS=="input47"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{capabilities/abs}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/ev}=="100007"
    ATTRS{capabilities/ff}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/key}=="2fc800 145200000000 0 10300 49e800000c00 e16800000000f f810000010000ffc"
    ATTRS{capabilities/led}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/msc}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/rel}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/snd}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/sw}=="0"
```

From what I can tell, there's not much in here which would allow me to detect my bluetooth headphones being connected, even the `input47` is an "input" not the audio sink (I'm assuming its a microphone but I could be wrong). Maybe there's a way to listen to bluez events (or pulseaudio events) but I haven't found it yet.

Can I write this sort of event handling with udev or bluez? If so, how?